# Rails where clause for :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following associations...

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
```

This allows me to do something like Event.last.tags and see all tags associated with an email. I'm trying to come up with a where clause for tags where I can do something like...

```
Event.where tag: 'my_tag'
```

When I do this I get:

```
2.1.3 :020 > Event.where tags: 'test'
  Event Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE `events`.`tags` = 'test'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'events.tags' in 'where clause': SELECT `events`.* FROM `events`  WHERE `events`.`tags` = 'test'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?:

```
Event.includes(:tags).where(tags: {name: 'my_tag'})
```

This will get all events with tags where tags' name is `'my_tag'`. Change `name` with the appropriate column name which exists in `tags` table for which you're trying to run query for.

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify the field of the tag record that contains 'my_tag'. For example, if the field is called name, then:

`Event.first.tags.where(name: 'my_tag')`